# Different output for Fiona Shapefile CRS

Tags: coordinate-system, fiona

I'm trying to read the crs property on a shapefile to validate projection. Below I contrast fiona documentation with what is output on my console.

Either output would be fine for my use case, but any idea why they are different?

*Documenation states:*
http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html#format-drivers-crs-bounds-and-schema

```
>>> c = fiona.open('docs/data/test_uk.shp')
>>> c.crs
>>> {'no_defs': True, 'ellps': 'WGS84', 'datum': 'WGS84', 'proj': 'longlat'}
```

I get, as if I were using **from_epsg**:

```
>>> {'init': u'epsg:4326'}
```

Are there scenarios where different shapefiles / prj formats yield different crs objects?

My .prj file:
  GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]

In looking at an additional shapefile with prj:
    PROJCS["USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Albers"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-96.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",29.5],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",45.5],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",37.5],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

I get the following output from c.crs:

```
{u'lon_0': -96, u'datum': u'NAD83', u'y_0': 0, u'no_defs': True, u'proj': u'aea', u'x_0': 0, u'units': u'm', u'lat_2': 45.5, u'lat_1': 29.5, u'lat_0': 37.5}
```

If I am just validating projection, is there a uniform interface besides .crs to get that info?

Comment: The crs format returned by Fiona is the [Proj.4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) format not the ESRI prj format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a difference between documentation and code. Recent versions of Fiona sniff out whether there's an entry in the EPSG table corresponding to the projection and preferentially return that.

Comment: And in Fiona 1.4.8, feature collections have a `crs_wkt` property that gives WKT strings.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, it's better to use Fiona here.

You can compare strings from your prj file for each layer using http://prj2epsg.org/search

You can also try to use OGR from Python like  below (except last line, it's an extraction from [the Python GDAL/OGR Cookbook](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/projection.html#get-projection)

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
dataset = driver.Open(r'c:\data\yourshpfile.shp')

# from Layer
layer = dataset.GetLayer()
spatialRef = layer.GetSpatialRef()
# from Geometry
feature = layer.GetNextFeature()
geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
spatialRef = geom.GetSpatialReference()
print spatialRef.ExportToWkt()
```

We choose to export to WKT here but doing `dir(spatialRef)` exposes various methods to export to different projection notations. It may help you to compare with other shapefiles.

See an excerpt from the output of `dir(spatialRef)`

```
 ...
 'ExportToMICoordSys',
 'ExportToPCI',
 'ExportToPrettyWkt',
 'ExportToProj4',
 'ExportToUSGS',
 'ExportToWkt',
 'ExportToXML',
 ...
```

In all case, you should also be aware that comparing projection is hard: the notation may change slightly but can affect or not the result you see on your screen or depending on the software (typically ArcGIS vs rest of the world)